# How to pop out a key-value pair from within a another key value pair in dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

My question is that how can I pop out say for example 'Phone#: ' or 'Email: ' or 'Area: ' because I know we can pop out the whole 'maulik' key and get rid of the entire key-value pair.

```
contacts = {
    'maulik':{'Phone#: ':1234567,'Email: ':'askm00@gmail.com','Area: ':'NorthBrunswick'},
    'jaysen':[2345678, 'ja69@it.edu','Iselin']
}
```

Comment: Are you just after this: `contacts['maulik'].pop('Phone#: ')` ?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `contacts['maulik']['Phone#: ']` or `del contacts['maulik']['Phone#: ']`